# when using NVM, unable to install npm packages globally

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, nvm

I am using NVM in windows, which basically switches between the versions of nodeJs by changing the shortcut it creates in "C:\program files\nodejs"

when I do

> nvm use 7.0

then the shortcut is updated to "c:\users\me\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v7.0"

if I use 4.6, then "c:\users\me\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v4.6"

As the actual node files sits inside NVM folder...

All the files inside "C:\program files\nodejs" are locked, becoz of this, when I run

> npm install -g package

, as part of installation process it tries to rename some files/directories, which it couldnt, and it fails....

```
-info using npm@3.10.8
-info using node@v7.0.0
-error Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\@angular\cli' -> 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\@angular\.cli.DELETE'
-error  Error
-error     at moveAway (C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v7.0.0\node_modules\npm\lib\install\action\finalize.js:38:5)
-error     at destStatted (C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v7.0.0\node_modules\npm\lib\install\action\finalize.js:27:7)
-error     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:111:15)
-error
-error Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\@angular\cli' -> 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\@angular\.cli.DELETE'
-error Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
-verbose exit [ -4048, true ]
```

I have been able to install packages globally before NVM, now I couldnt.
I tried unlocking "program files\nodejs\node_modules" no errors, but the dir remains locked.

unlocking  may not be the right approach as whenever we switch to other node version, it will get locked again.

I dont have admin rights, but that shouldnt be a problem i suppose...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is exactly with admin rights.

As a workaround, you can install package inside your project, and access it's binary in `./node_modules/.bin/` folder.

Comment: that solution is helpful, thanks.  But I would like to run these commands in my project directory, rather than in .bin folder.  For eg, if I use **ng new my-app**, then it creates the files and folder in .bin

Comment: as another workaround - add your `.bin` folder to the `PATH` variable :)

Comment: in git bash, created an alias ng='/c/Projects/sample/node_modules/.bin/ng.cmd'